# How to read the parent form datagrid into child form

Tags: windows, winforms, mdichild, mdiparent

How to read the parent form datagrid into child form.

In the Parent Form Datagrid and read into Child form.

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you question is regarding data design or ui functionality.  It all starts with the data.  Create an ID field in the Parent table.  When you insert records into the Child table include the Parent ID field.  Then in your datagrid when a user clicks the Select button you can pass that ID to the Child table to isolate the related records. This is what they call a Master/Child relationship.  Hope that helps. Rob. FormThis.com